# Want to Cache or session webresponse in Class library project in C#

Tags: c#, caching, webresponse

Using below scenario in class library project

For storing and fetching the `Webresponse` from Cache

```
System.Web.HttpRuntime.Cache["cacheKey"] = resp;    
resp1 = (WebResponse)System.Web.HttpRuntime.Cache["cacheKey"];

resp = resp1;
doc.Load(resp.GetResponseStream());
```

ERROR : Roor element is missing 
But during fetching, webresponse is different from the webresponse which gets stored.
Error didn't come when I directly pass the response
Can anybody suggest me the reason or some other better code?
Or should I go for using session?

Comment: Do you use MVC? If so, MVC has a built-in caching mechanism.

Comment: No, I am using this in Class library project

Comment: what are the differences?

Comment: Do you want to use client side caching or server side caching?